# UWP: Accessing Usercontrol and elements Inside Usercontrol from parent listview

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, binding

My XAML is as below.:

```
<ComboBox  x:Name="cbCurrencyValueList" SelectionChanged="cbCurrencyValueList_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyCurrencyLists}, Path=librarycurrencylist}" DisplayMemberPath="CurrencyCode" SelectedValuePath="CurrencyCode"  SelectedValue="{Binding PricingCurrency, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

<ListView x:Name="lbPriceChangeSchedule" ItemsSource="{Binding PricingScheduleList}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <ComboBox  x:Name="cbSchedulePriceValueList"  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyPricingLists}, Path=librarypricinglist}" DisplayMemberPath="PriceValue" SelectedValuePath="PriceValue"  SelectedValue="{Binding ScheduleDisplayPricing, Mode=TwoWay}" />

                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

**Question**: Any selection change in 'cbCurrencyValueList' combobox will change the itemssource list of cbSchedulePriceValueList inside listview. if listview contains n instance of ComboBox  cbSchedulePriceValueList then all of them's itemsource will change.

***So how can I access every instance of cbSchedulePriceValueList in codebehind and update/change its itemssource individually.?***

Any guidance ?

Comment: If you want to update/change its itemssource in code-behind, you just need to change the property which bound with itemsSource. If changing the property, can it achieve the effect you want? If can't, can you provide more code snippet and describe more details about your expected behavior?